# Binding attached property to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, crystal-reports, attached-properties

I am using the new WPF Viewer for Crystal Reports in C#. As I am using MVVM, I would really like to bind the source of the data to be displayed instead of doing this in the loaded event. Therefore, I wanted to implement an attached property for the source - but the binding just doesn't work, the Getter method is not even called. The other posts about binding attached properties also didn't help and I am not sure what I am doing different. Can anybody help? Here is my simplified code for the attached property:

```
public static class CrystalReportsAttached {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Source",
            typeof(IEnumerable),
            typeof(CrystalReportsAttached),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableList<Participant>() as IEnumerable, SourceChanged));

    public static void SetSource(DependencyObject target, IEnumerable value) {
        target.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static IEnumerable GetSource(DependencyObject target) {
        return (IEnumerable)target.GetValue(SourceProperty);
    }

    private static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        CrystalReportsViewer reportViewer = d as CrystalReportsViewer;
        if (reportViewer != null) {
            MyCrystalReport report = new MyCrystalReport();
            report.SetDataSource(d.GetValue(SourceProperty) as IEnumerable);
            reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
        }
    }
}
```

where `MyCrystalReport` is the wrapper around my rpt report file.

If I bind to the source like this now, it's not working:

```
<my:CrystalReportsViewer prop:CrystalReportsAttached.Source="{Binding MyList, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I tried to bind a `DataGrid`s `ItemsSource` in the same way and that works, so there seems to be no mistake with the path name or smth similar.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't already use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) or some other tool for debugging bindings, I'd recommend you start. Maybe the attached property is updating , but are you sure the `my:CrystalReportsViewer` is bound to it correctly?

Comment: that seems to be a pretty interesting project, I actually never used smth like that. Thanks for the hint, I will have a look on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out where the problem was:

It seems like the `CrystalReportViewer`'s DataContext is overridden for some reason. Therefore, the binding worked in every other context (e.g. in a `DataGrid`), but not here. I found out the problem by using the [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) tool mentioned by [default.kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644812/default-kramer) above. I could fix it by changing the binding to

```
<my:CrystalReportsViewer prop:CrystalReportsAttached.Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Participants, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

so it does access the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` (which should usually be the same as the one for the specific control, but is not for `CrystalReportsViewer`) and it is working now.

Thanks for everybody's help!

Answer (score 2):

With dependency properties, all you can ever be certain of is that your property changed callback will be called when the property changes and that the underlying property will actually be changed **if** your getter is called.  This might seem strange but your getter and setter just access that underlying property, so if the XAML parser calls `target.GetValue(SourceProperty)` it gets the correct thing without calling your getter.

The real question is does your property changed callback get called?

Comment: hmm, that's interesting. However, I set breakpoints almost everywhere and my property changed callback also does not get called. It only gets called if I don't use a binding as I did with another `DependencyProperty` which is a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

To receive changes to the collection, the source collection must implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

You can use ObservableCollection, find a custom notifying collection online, or wrap an existing collection with a class that you write that implements the interface of the inner collection and INotifyCollectionChanged.

If the initial binding fails, check that you have set the DataContext (to your View-Model), that the property name on the VM is correct and that the property has a public getter.

Edit:

This part is wrong:

```
new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableList<Participant>() as IEnumerable, SourceChanged));
```

You are setting the same list instance as the default value for all controls.
Set the default value in the constructor instead (put null in the DP reg. line).

Comment: `MyList` is of type `ObservableList` which I implemented and it does implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Also, the class containing the `MyList` property implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` as it is a `ViewModel`. As I said, it works if I use a `DataGrid` and set the `ItemsSource` property to `MyList` instead, so the problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: Have you tried using ICollection instead, I'm not sure what interface WPF's collection control looks for. Also see edit.

Comment: Okay, I already tried that and changed it back now to `new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SourceChanged))`: Isn't that only for the default value, so it should be overridden by the getter value? It still does not work though, sorry. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why is the attached DP on a static class? - They are usually on container classes. I'll rephrase this as an answer later :-)

Comment: hadn't read your comment yet. I tried to change the DependencyProperty to `ObservableList<Participant>` now, but it still does not work. `ObservableList` extends `List` and implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so I think all necessary interfaces should be implemented there.

Comment: I only put static there as I saw some other attached properties with the `static` attribute. I tried both (with or without the `static` attribute), but none of them is working :(.

Comment: I meant why is the class static, not the property. Attached properties are meant to be defined on controls that contain the control on which you are setting the attached property. E.g. Grid.Row on a Label within a containing Grid.

Comment: if you mean the class `CrystalReportsAttached`, that's what I meant in my comment, sorry if I wasn't too clear about that. If you mean smth. else I don't understand it...

Comment: That is what I meant. Is CrystalReportsViewer under the CrystalReportsAttached in the XAML tree?